# UICollectionView only returning One Section?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, sections

I have 3 `collectionViews` in one Controller. Everything in each `collectionView` is set up perfectly fine except for one thing, setting more than one section always returns one section!

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    switch collectionView {
    case oneCollectionView:
        return 1
    case twoCollectionView:
        return 3
    case threeCollectionView:
        return 5
    default:
        return 10
    }
}
```

Even when I set the number of items individually and give custom `backgroundColors` depending on which section I'm in.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch collectionView {
    case oneCollectionView:
            return 25
    case twoCollectionView:
        return 10
    case threeCollectionView:
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return 200
        case 1:
            return 300
        case 2:
            return 5
        default:
            return 1
        }
    default:
        return 1
    }
}
```

And this is for every collectionView! I thought adding headers would work, but that produced no result either. Might there be a reason all of the colectionViews only display 1 section?

Answer (score 2):

So I finally figured out the problem. when using

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

}
```

It gives no compile errors, but it doesn't return what you specify. Using this instead

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
}
```

Displays the sections. Rather frustrating to figure out.